# Hiding GET parameters in php

Tags: php, url

I am working on local machine and my URL is:

```
http://localhost:91/GlobalVision/index.php?mm=1&sm=1 

     <? $mm=$_GET["mm"];
                 $sm=$_GET["sm"]; ?>
              <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
                <li class=" <? if($mm==1) echo "active" ?>  treeview">
                  <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li <? if($mm==1 && $sm==1) echo "class=\"active\"" ?>><a href="index.php?mm=1&sm=1"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard1</a></li>
                    <li <? if($mm==1 && $sm==2) echo "class=\"active\"" ?>><a href="index2.php?mm=1&sm=2"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> index2</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
</ul>
```

i have created this file as separate menu file and included in other php files.
i wanted url as:

```
http://localhost:91/GlobalSDK/index
```

I tried writing:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+)/$ index.php?mm=$1&sm=$2 [L]
```

this rules in `.htaccess` file but it gives me error.

What should be the rule to achieve this. Even when index page get change it should display only page name not parameters. What should be the rule for this?

Comment: Use Post method or use data encryption

Comment: You can't hide `$_GET` parameters if your request method is GET

Comment: i cant use post method because i am sending this parameters from url Encoding. @Ranautos what is data encryption and how to use it...?

Comment: Can you post the code that generates your URL?

Comment: @Alan Machado please see the updated question

Comment: Hiding get doesn't make sense, since there is $_POST, this would be a useless workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Try these methods

> 1) Use a form and `POST` the information.
>
> 2) Use `session` variables to carry information from page to page.
>
> 3) Use "`encoded`" or non-sensical information in the QueryString in
>   place of the real data.